# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable constructor: <New id="IADD" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource"><Arg>

Tags: java, maven, jndi, embedded-jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I am  trying to create an embedded jetty server with JNDI. But somehow before start up I get the below error after i do mvn jetty:run.

I see all steps are completed  but before server starts I get this error

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ ismart-project-app-web ---
[INFO] Using 'Cp1252' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\workspaceeNewEmbedded\ismart-project-app-web\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ ismart-project-app-web ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< jetty-maven-plugin:9.4.37.v20210219:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ ismart-project-app-web <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jetty-maven-plugin:9.4.37.v20210219:run (default-cli) @ ismart-project-app-web ---
[INFO] Logging initialized @80224ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[INFO] webAppSourceDirectory not set. Trying src\main\webapp
[INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
[INFO] nonBlocking:false
[INFO] Classes = C:\workspaceeNewEmbedded\ismart-project-app-web\target\classes
[INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: ismart-project-app-web
[INFO] Context path = /IADD
[INFO] Tmp directory = C:\workspaceeNewEmbedded\ismart-project-app-web\target\tmp
[INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
[INFO] web.xml file = file:///C:/workspaceeNewEmbedded/ismart-project-app-web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
[INFO] Webapp directory = C:\workspaceeNewEmbedded\ismart-project-app-web\src\main\webapp
[INFO] jetty-9.4.37.v20210219; built: 2021-02-19T15:16:47.689Z; git: 27afab2bd37780d179836e313e0fe11bc4fa0ce9; jvm 1.8.0_221-b27
[WARNING] Config error at <Set name="Url">URLD</Set>
[WARNING] Config error at <New id="IADD" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource"><Arg>jdbc/IADD</Arg><Arg>
   <New class="Class"><Set name="Url">URLD</Set><Set name="User">User</Set><Set name="Password">Password</Set></New>
 </Arg></New>
[WARNING] Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@2ef60909{/IADD,file:///C:/workspaceeNewEmbedded/ismart-project-app-web/src/main/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{file:///C:/workspaceeNewEmbedded/ismart-project-app-web/src/main/webapp/}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable constructor: <New id="IADD" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource"><Arg>jdbc/IADD</Arg><Arg>
   <New class="Class"><Set name="Url">URLD</Set><Set name="User">User</Set><Set name="Password">Password</Set></New>
 </Arg></New> on o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@2ef60909{/IADD,file:///C:/workspaceeNewEmbedded/ismart-project-app-web/src/main/webapp/,STARTING}{file:///C:/workspaceeNewEmbedded/ismart-project-app-web/src/main/webapp/}
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.newObj (XmlConfiguration.java:1015)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure (XmlConfiguration.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure (XmlConfiguration.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure (XmlConfiguration.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration.lambda$configure$0 (EnvConfiguration.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.runWithServerClassAccess (WebAppClassLoader.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration.configure (EnvConfiguration.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure (WebAppContext.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext (WebAppContext.java:1409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart (ContextHandler.java:911)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart (ServletContextHandler.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart (WebAppContext.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart (JettyWebAppContext.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start (Server.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart (Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty (AbstractJettyMojo.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute (AbstractJettyMojo.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute (JettyRunMojo.java:150)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] Started ServerConnector@48c48cd2{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
[INFO] Started @85996ms
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
```

My pom.xml looks like below I am using jetty-9.4.37.v20210219

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>fakegroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>ismart-project-app-web</artifactId>
    <version>V1.${BUILD_NUMBER}</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>ismart-project-app-web</name>
    <url></url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>Cp1252</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <asm.version>3.3</asm.version>
        <axis.version>1.4.1</axis.version>
        <bsh.version>2.0b4</bsh.version>
        <commons-beanutils.version>1.9.4</commons-beanutils.version>
        <commons-collections.version>3.2.2</commons-collections.version>
        <commons-csv.version>1.6</commons-csv.version>
        <commons-io.version>2.6</commons-io.version>
        <commons-lang.version>2.6</commons-lang.version>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.11</commons-lang3.version>
        <commons-net.version>3.6</commons-net.version>
        <dom4j.version>2.1.3</dom4j.version>
        <dwr.version>3.0.2-RELEASE</dwr.version>
        <ehcache.version>2.10.6</ehcache.version>
        <gson.version>1.4</gson.version>
        <hibernate-core.version>3.6.10.Final</hibernate-core.version>
        <httpclient.version>4.5.13</httpclient.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jfreechart.version>1.0.19</jfreechart.version>
        <jfreecommon.version>1.0.23</jfreecommon.version>
        <jsch.version>0.1.55</jsch.version>
        <json.version>20180813</json.version>
        <jsqlparser.version>1.4</jsqlparser.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <log4j.version>2.13.2</log4j.version>
        <opencsv.version>2.3</opencsv.version>
        <openjpa.version>2.3.0</openjpa.version>
        <poi.version>4.1.1</poi.version>
        <quartz.version>2.3.2</quartz.version>
        <slf4j-log4j12.version>1.7.25</slf4j-log4j12.version>
        <struts2.version>2.5.26</struts2.version>
        <springframwork.version>4.3.26.RELEASE</springframwork.version>
        <snakeyaml.version>1.27</snakeyaml.version>     
        <xlsx-streamer.version>2.1.0</xlsx-streamer.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.websphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.ws.admin.client</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0.9</version>
            <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->    
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.security</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${springframwork.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframwork.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-collections.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.directwebremoting</groupId>
            <artifactId>dwr</artifactId>
            <version>${dwr.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-net.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-beanutils.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-csv.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>${gson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>${dom4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>${jsch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${ehcache.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId> <artifactId>axis</artifactId> 
            <version>${axis.version}</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>${quartz.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>HikariCP-java6</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>${json.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>${jfreechart.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
            <version>${jfreecommon.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jsqlparser</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsqlparser</artifactId>
            <version>${jsqlparser.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>${opencsv.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId> <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId> 
            <version>${openjpa.version}</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.monitorjbl</groupId>
            <artifactId>xlsx-streamer</artifactId>
            <version>${xlsx-streamer.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
                    <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>${asm.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.beanshell</groupId> <artifactId>bsh</artifactId> 
            <version>${bsh.version}</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId> 
            <version>${slf4j-log4j12.version}</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>${snakeyaml.version}</version>            
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
                <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>IADD</finalName>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven 
                defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
             <!-- <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <port>9090</port>
          <path>/IADD/</path>
        </configuration>
      </plugin> -->
      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.37.v20210219</version>
    <configuration>
        <webApp>
            <contextPath>/IADD</contextPath>
        </webApp>
        <systemProperties>
        <systemProperty>
        <name>fakeNamePath</name>
        <value>LOCAL</value>
        </systemProperty>
        <systemProperty>
        <name>fakeNamePath</name>
        <value>1</value>
        </systemProperty>
        <systemProperty>
        <name>fakeNamePath</name>
        <value>70</value>
        </systemProperty>
        </systemProperties>
 <!-- <jettyEnvXml>src/main/resources/jetty-env.xml</jettyEnvXml>  -->
    </configuration>
     <dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
  <version>19.3.0.0</version>
          <type>jar</type>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <filesets>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>target</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*</include>
                                </includes>
                                <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                            </fileset>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>src/main/generated</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*</include>
                                </includes>
                                <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                            </fileset>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>./src/main/resources/META-INF</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>MANIFEST.MF</include>
                                </includes>
                                <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                            </fileset>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>./src/main/webapp/META-INF</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>MANIFEST.MF</include>
                                </includes>
                                <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                            </fileset>
                        </filesets>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12.4</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            

    

<version>2.2</version>
                </plugin>
                  
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>IADD</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
      <param-name>debug</param-name>
      <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>detail</param-name>
      <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>validate</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
        

    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <description>DWR Servlet</description>
        <display-name>DWR Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>

        <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>crossDomainSessionSecurity</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>allowGetForSafariButMakeForgeryEasier</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    <context-param>
         <param-name>quartz:config-file</param-name>
         <param-value>fakePath</param-value>
     </context-param>
     <context-param>
         <param-name>quartz:shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
     </context-param>
     <context-param>
         <param-name>quartz:wait-on-shutdown</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
     </context-param>
     <context-param>
         <param-name>quartz:start-on-load</param-name>
         <param-value>false</param-value>
     </context-param>

     <listener>
         <listener-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener</listener-class>
     </listener>
     
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>scheduler</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>fakeClass</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>iSmartLogin</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    
    <listener>
        <listener-class>fakeClass</listener-class>
    </listener>
     <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/IADD</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref> 
    
</web-app>
```

My jetty-env.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
 <Configure id='wac' class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
 <New id="IADD"  class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
  <Arg><Ref refid="wac"/></Arg>
  <Arg>jdbc/IADD</Arg>
  <Arg>
   <New class="Class">
  <!--   <Set name="DriverType">thin</Set> -->
    <Set name="Url">URLD</Set>
    <Set name="User">User</Set>
   
    <Set name="Password">Password</Set>
   
    <!-- <Set name="connectionCachingEnabled">true</Set> -->
    <!-- <Set name="connectionCacheProperties">
     <New class="java.util.Properties">
      <Call name="setProperty">
        <Arg>InitialLimit</Arg>
        <Arg>5</Arg>
      </Call>
      <Call name="setProperty">
        <Arg>MaxLimit</Arg>
        <Arg>20</Arg>
      </Call>
      <Call name="setProperty">
        <Arg>ValidateConnection</Arg>
        <Arg>true</Arg>
      </Call>
     </New>
   </Set> -->
 </New>
 </Arg>
 </New>
 
 
</Configure>
```

Can anyone peae help me with this? I am stuck badly for the last 6 hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class you specified `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`.

Does not implement the `javax.sql.DataSource` interface that is required for this `org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource`.

You have many class options, depending on your version of Oracle server installed, your version of oracle jdbc jar file, and if you have other requirements (like transactions, pooling, etc.).

Just pick the correct class for the `<New class="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver">` line (that's what's wrong with your current setup)